# What do I need to be able to delete a user's workspace?

Tags: tfs

I need to delete the workspace of a user that has some files checked out.

My account is a member of `Administration Console users`, `TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG` and the `Application Tier`'s `Team Foundation Administrators` group.

The `Team Foundation Administrators` group has all privileges except "`Make requests on behalf of others`":

```
Administer Warehouse
Create Team Project Collection
Delete Team Project Collection
Edit Instance-level information
```

<strike>Make requests on behalf of others</strike>

```
Trigger events
Use full Web Access features
View instance-level information
```

I can access the `Team Foundation Server Administration Console`, but the `File` menu only has "`Exit`".

I understand that I can also do this from the `tf` utility, but I can't find it or perhaps I don't have this utility installed (Where can I look for it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Visual Studio 201x Team Explorer you'll get tf.exe.

Here is the 2013 link 
[VS 2013 Team Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40776)

Then you can find tf.exe here:

Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

If the user has not left the company then you can just undo their pending changes:

> tf.exe undo /workspace

[tf.exe undo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4.aspx)

Or if you really want to delete the workspace completely:

> tf.exe workspace /delete

[Tf.exe Workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se.aspx)

Some more details on command line tools for tfs:
[Command Line tools for TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253088.aspx)

Comment: To bulk delete workspaces you can use TFS Sidekicks.